# GStreamer and dynamic subtitles

Tags: gstreamer, subtitle, kate, matroska

I am new to GStreamer and am trying to encode a video stream (for now v4l2src) with a subtitle stream and muxed into a matroska container. I am able to pass in a .srt file with subtitles that are then encoded into the text stream. However I am wanting to use the subtitle stream to encode 'metadata' that is generated while the video is being recorded. I could use textoverlay but do not want to burn the meta-data onto the image. I want to do this later (After a variety of post-production effects).

Is there a way that I can add subtitles into the matroskamux as time passes? The content of the subtitle text is not known before hand, for example the gps coords of a moving camera.

Is this the best approach for recording meta-data in matroska stream?

Here is my GStreamer pipeline, form the pov of gst-launch :

gst-launch-0.10 matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mkv \ v4l2src ! x264enc ! mux. \ filesrc location=subtest.txt ! subparse ! kateenc category=SUB ! mux.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late now, but WebM has WebVTT support for subtitles of kind metadata.